# Replace html tags with whitespaces

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm using method `strip_tags` which removes all tags from my string, however after removing some of my text lacking of whitespaces, especially where 1 tag ends and another begins. Is there any way to insert whitespaces into place where tags were removed? Look for ex. below

```
str
 => "<span>Class GOesHere</span><div>SomeExtra Tag</div>" 

helper.strip_tags(str)
 => "Class GOesHereSomeExtra Tag"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
str
 => "<span>Class GOesHere</span><div>SomeExtra Tag</div>"
```

You could change your string before striping tags, for example

```
str.gsub!('><', '> <')
```

and it should produce

```
str
 => "<span>Class GOesHere</span> <div>SomeExtra Tag</div>"
```

Comment: It will not work if you have a simple tag like `<br>`

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend parsing the HTML and extracting the text.  [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/), a very well known gem should help solve this with ease:

```
require 'nokogiri'
=> false
> str = "<span>Class GOesHere</span><div>SomeExtra Tag</div>"
=> "<span>Class GOesHere</span><div>SomeExtra Tag</div>"
> Nokogiri::HTML(str).text
=> "Class GOesHereSomeExtra Tag"
```

**Update**:

This will search all text nodes in the html and map the text content.  The resultant array is concatenated with a space separator:

```
> Nokogiri::HTML(str).xpath('//text()').map(&:text).join(' ')
=> "Class GOesHere SomeExtra Tag"
```

Comment: I absolutely agree about using an HTML parser in this case but the output is just the same as the OP currently has.

Comment: Added a solution. Thanks @HamZa for pointing that out.  I misread the last part.

Answer (score 4):

Try using regex like this:

```
str.gsub!(/<.*?>/, " ")
# => " Class GOesHere  SomeExtra Tag "
```

Comment: `.*?` means everything inside of `<>` ?

Comment: yes in a non-greedy way. If you remove `?` it will become greedy and replace the whole string with `" "`

Comment: Basically it will break at `<p title="a > b">foo</p>`

Comment: @HamZa thats true. I am handling only basic examples.